# using python want to calculate last 6 months average for each month

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, datetime, average

I have a dataframe which has 3 columns [user_id ,year_month & value] , i want to calculate last 6months average for the year automatically for each individual unique user_id and assign it to new column

```
 user_id  value     year_month
    1      50       2021-01
    1      54       2021-02
   ..       ..           ..
    1      50       2021-11
    1      47       2021-12
    2      36       2021-01
    2     48.5      2021-05
    ..     ..         ..
    2     54        2021-11
    2     30.2      2021-12
    3     41.4      2021-01
    3     48.5      2021-02
    3     41.4      2021-05
    ..     ..         ..
    3     30.2      2021-12

     Total year has 12-24 months 
      to get jan 2022 value[dec 2021 to july 2021]=[55+32+33+63+54+51]/6
      to get feb 2022 value[jan 2022 to aug 2021] =[32+33+37+53+54+51]/6
      to get mar 2022 value[feb 2022 to sep 2021] =[45+32+33+63+54+51]/6
      to get apr 2022 value[mar 2022 to oct 2021] =[63+54+51+45+32+33]/6
```

Comment: `.groupby` and `. rolling` are what you need

Comment: @PaulH : thanks for swift response i need both

Answer (score 0):

First index, your datetime column

```
df = df.set_index('year_month')
```

Then do the following

```
df.groupby('UserId').rolling('6M').transform('avg')
```

This is the most correct way but hey here is one more intutitive

```
df.sort_values('year_month').groupby('UserId').rolling(6).transform('avg') # Returns wanted series
```

As paul h said

Comment: am getting error : ValueError: <6 * MonthEnds> is a non-fixed frequency